# Algorithm that can connect small gaps in contour image

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, image-processing, contour

I'm developing an algorithm to segment images of fibers. For this purpose I'm using Canny in Python algorithm for their edge detection. The produced contours are good but the problem is in small gaps that makes me unable to fill each element with specific color.

So the general question, whick algorithm can help to connect that small gaps between the contours?

Image with gaps in contours:

[image]

This is how I would like to connect them:

[image]

Morphological closing, dilatin, erosion don't work.

My idea is to go though the whole image with 5x5 kernel. And if there are two different parts within this kernel, connect them. But I haven't figured out how to implement it yet. Any ideas?

Comment: It is necessary to clarify the rules of how and where to connect (,or not).
I think that you should consider whether you can really define the rule with only binary edge image as input or not.

Answer (score 0):

Define a structuringElement, then dilate the edges to fill in the gaps, then erode the newly dilated edges to the original size.

you might be able to do some variation with fancy loops if there are artefacts present

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. When you dilate a line with a gap it anyway remain as a thin point and appear when the line will be eroded. And I cant dilate the image a lot otherwise the information will disappear. Here are a couple of examples

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJhVz.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPHnW.jpg

Comment: Is it possible to get a structuringElement that will dilate/erode lines only at the tip?